# can apache sentry support Row-Level access?

Tags: apache-sentry

As we know ,apache sentry support column-level access,however,I got a case here:
data of group A and Group B both in one hive table,so user of group A just need to query data of Group A,and has no privilege to query data of group B,so I wonder apache sentry supoort my case?

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to create separate views for Group A and Group B users with sentry access restrictions.

second solution is to implement the CDH service called recordservice (in beta release) provides both column and row level security.